# How to load Wiktionary XML dump into Virtuoso?

Tags: xml, rdf, virtuoso, wiktionary

I am new to [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) and [RDF](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Resource_Description_Framework).

I am trying to develop a n-triple store for [Wiktionary](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Wiktionary) dump in Virtuoso. The dump I downloaded from [the Wikimedia site](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/) was in XML form.

Can anyone give me instructions or links that I can refer to load my Wiktionary data into Virtuoso to create SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: You can't load simple XML if the store is based on RDF triples. By they way, there is an RDF dump for Wiktionary.

Comment: AKSW, can you please give me the link to that? I tried to find it, but couldn't.

Comment: Google Query: "Wiktionary RDF dump" -> second link: http://dbpedia.org/wiktionary-rdf-extraction

Comment: There was a note on DBPedia's mailing list re. Wiktionary extraction (saying it is not supported now but they are looking for volunteers to renew work on this topic): https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/message/34885382/

Comment: In that case, is there a way to get the structure of the xml file? I am thinking of writing a code to get the n-tuples from xml file.

Comment: I would suggest you work with the WIktionary and DBpedia folks, and start with the code they've already written. [As they say](http://dbpedia.org/wiktionary-rdf-extraction), extraction efforts are being coordinated via the [Wiktionary mailing list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/wiktionary-l).